# Declare global variable with items in NSArray?

Tags: ios, nsarray, global-variables

I want to implement a feature that when I clicked the "operatorButton" the titleColor changed,But when I clicked other Button besides "operatorButton",the "operatorButton" titleColor backto originalColor.

Here I got a problem: 
the "operatorButton" I declared in "viewDidLoad" method is local variable，I can not access in other method.
How do I declare the "operatorButton"as a global variable that represent every items in NSArray "operationButton"?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *operationButton;    


- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
for (UIButton *operatorButton  in  self.operationButton){
    [operatorButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:248.0/255 green:148.0/255 blue:52.0/255 alpha:1.0]
                         forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [operatorButton setTitleColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:95.0/255 green:105.0/255 blue:114.0/255 alpha:1.0]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

}
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Do you want the button to change color when the user is tapping it, or are you trying to make radio buttons, where only one button is selected (orange), and the others are deselected (gray)?

Comment: @user3386109  I want to make it like the system calculator,when one operator button pressed,other operator button unselected.when number button pressed,all operator button unselected.

Comment: Ah ok, well it looks like LyricalPanda already has a suggestion for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already declared it as an array with the IBOutletCollection. You can access self.operationButton anywhere in that file since it's a property.

Create one `IBAction` for all the buttons, then try the following:

```
-(IBAction)selectedButton:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
  for (UIButton *operatorButton in self.operationButton)
  {
    if ([operatorButton isEqualTo:senderButton])
    {
      //set title color to your selected Color
    }
    else
    {
      //set title color to original color on buttons not clicked
    }
  }
}
```